# Extract string that matches pattern and is located between two defined strings

Tags: php, regex

So I've got a string which looks like this:

```
profile=123456&imagehd=image%20profile%20123456.hd.jpg&imagesd=image%20profile%20123456.sd.jpg&name=test_user
```

What I would like to do is with help from a regex pattern extract the imagehd and the imagesd strings (`image%20profile%20123456.hd.jpg` and `image%20profile%20123456.sd.jpg`). I have no experience with regex patterns and that's why I'm asking you guys. I was thinking, to ease things up to just run the string through an url decoder to make it usable and then fetch the strings.

The strings are located between the `imagehd=` and the `&` (for the HD image) and between `imagesd=` and the `&` (for the SD image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
preg_match('~(?<=imagehd=)[^&]+~', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it. Is it possible to add so it searches for both *imagehd=* and *imagesd=* in the same preg_match?

Comment: @MagnusBurton: Yes it is with: `preg_match_all('~(?<=imagehd=)(?<hd>[^&]+)|(?<=imagesd=)(?<sd>[^&]+)~', $string, $matches);` But take a look at @NiettheDarkAbsol answer that is easier and more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use more appropriate functions?

```
parse_str($your_string_here, $data);
// now $data is all your data
echo $data['imagehd'];
echo "\n";
echo $data['imagesd'];
```

[`parse_str` documentation](http://php.net/parse-str)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't even need regular expressions for this. Instead, you can use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), which treats the string as a query string, and constructs an array out of it. You'll then have `$imagehd` and `$imagesd` as variables.